# exposing borders lines of Label widget in kivy

Tags: kivy, widget, label

I have a boxlayout (1) of two labels placed next to each other.  I use this widget to build to  another boxlayout containing a list of the widgets of (1).
For readability,  I like to have each line separated by a thin line and I also like to have a vertical line to separate two labels.
something similar to:

| Label 1 content | label 2 content |
| --- | --- |
| Label 1 content 1 | label 2 content 2 |
| :----------------: | :-----------------: |

etc. And alternate the back ground color of each line.
Could I get some help in how to do this, please.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a background color, then define `Labels` that obscure that background color except for a small area around the `Labels`. Here is a `kv` file that does that:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    spacing: 2
    padding: 2
    
    # define background that will appear as outlines
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,0,0,1  # outline color
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 2
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        LabelNotTransparent:
            text: 'Label 1 content'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
        LabelNotTransparent:
            text: 'Label 2 content'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 2
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        LabelNotTransparent:
            text: 'Label 1 content 1'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
        LabelNotTransparent:
            text: 'Label 2 content 2'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 2
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        LabelNotTransparent:
            text: ':----------------:'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
        LabelNotTransparent:
            text: ':----------------:'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
<LabelNotTransparent@Label>:
    # normal Labels are transparent, this makes it not transparent
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,0,0,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

The `spacing` and `padding` values are the areas that will show through and appear as outlines.

Comment: Thanks so much, going to try it.  Do appreciate your help.